Is it: 'Everything, like cars and trucks, is important¨', or 'Everything, like cars and trucks, are important.'?
Is it: 'Everything, like cars and trucks, is important¨', or 'Everything, like cars and trucks, are important.'?
I want to use is, but suddenly with cars and trucks, everything has become kind of countable.

Does this answer your question? Singular or plural verb after parenthetical material containing a conjunction? The rule given there in Byron's answer is general for all parentheticals, not just those containing a conjunction. But it does advise that fewer hackles will be often raised if one rephrases: 'Everything, including cars and trucks, is important'. Here, 'everything' does not sit well too close to  'cars and trucks'.

... Using 'including' positions the 'cars and trucks' within the universal set, and 'everything' takes singular agreement, as you say.

What do you want your text to mean? If what you mean is Everything which is like a car or a truck is important, you shouldn't have a comma. The alternative with a comma implies a prior context within which it's already understood that cars and trucks are important. The utterance with comma / pause asserts that everything is as important as cars and trucks. But regardless of that, everything is the syntactic subject, and everything is always singular.

"Scott, like many men, enjoy football"? Nope.
